How to outer merge dataframes with multiindexes without dropping indexes?
I have two dataframes, each with a MultiIndex.  I want to outer merge them on their common index.  Doing so ends up with the non-common indexes disappearing.  How do I avoid this?
Set up:
import pandas as pd
tuples1 = [(1,'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b')]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'x':[1,2,3,4]}, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples1,names=['number', 'letter']))

tuples2 = [(1, 'red'), (1, 'blue'), (2, 'red'), (2, 'blue')]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'y':[10,20,30,40]}, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples2,names=['number', 'color']))

This creates two dataframes:
               x
number letter
1      a       1
       b       2
2      a       3
       b       4

               y
number color
1      red    10
       blue   20
2      red    30
       blue   40

This is my code to outer merge them on number:
merged = df1.merge(df2, on=['number'], how='outer')

This is what I get:
        x   y
number
1       1  10
1       1  20
1       2  10
1       2  20
2       3  30
2       3  40
2       4  30
2       4  40

This is what I want:
                     x   y
number letter color
1      a      red    1  10
              blue   1  20
       b      red    2  10
              blue   2  20
2      a      red    3  30
              blue   3  40
       b      red    4  30
              blue   4  40

I have looked at a lot of other StackOverflow posts without success in finding a relevant answer.

That's actually quite simple, you can join:
out = df1.join(df2, how='outer')

Output:
                     x   y
number letter color       
1      a      red    1  10
              blue   1  20
       b      red    2  10
              blue   2  20
2      a      red    3  30
              blue   3  40
       b      red    4  30
              blue   4  40


This solved my problem.  Thank you.

Another possible solution, based on merge:
df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')

Output:
                     x   y
number letter color       
1      a      red    1  10
              blue   1  20
       b      red    2  10
              blue   2  20
2      a      red    3  30
              blue   3  40
       b      red    4  30
              blue   4  40


This is simply done this way:
import pandas as pd

tuples1 = [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b')]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples1, names=['number', 'letter']))

tuples2 = [(1, 'red'), (1, 'blue'), (2, 'red'), (2, 'blue')]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'y': [10, 20, 30, 40]}, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples2, names=['number', 'color']))

df1_reset = df1.reset_index()
df2_reset = df2.reset_index()

merged = df1_reset.merge(df2_reset, on='number', how='outer')
merged = merged.set_index(['number', 'letter', 'color'])

print(merged)

which gives
                     x   y
number letter color       
1      a      red    1  10
              blue   1  20
       b      red    2  10
              blue   2  20
2      a      red    3  30
              blue   3  40
       b      red    4  30
              blue   4  40

So, you need to reset the indices of the original dataframes, perform the merge, and then reapply the MultiIndex afterward.
